# JSF shows uninterpreted page when adding slash to path

Tags: jsf, xhtml

I have the problem, that JSF is showing the original source code page, when calling for exmaple ..../index.xhtml/ instead of the normal path .../index.xhtml

By adding the additional slash at the end of the path, it shows the unrendered page. How can I turn off this behaviour?

I use spring boot with JSF 2.2.13. I register JSF in my Spring Config with the following line.

```
ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new FacesServlet(), "*.xhtml");
```

It's all working fine, we just discovered this odd behaviour when adding the additional slash.

Any suggestions how to avoid this?

Comment: This is not the default behavior. Likely "Spring Config" is doing something wrong. E.g. having a badly configured front controller or static resources servlet or filter. I recommend to reframe your question as this has technically nothing to do with JSF nor "XHTML" and that you'd most likely face exactly the same problem when using any other view technology than JSF/Facelets.

Comment: Why would anybody want to add a slash after the file name anyway? That's not what slashes are for...

Comment: A tester found it by accident ... normally it would never happen. But never say never :)

Comment: I fixed it by letting spring remove all trailing slashes